# PnP Powershell - SPO - request channel timed out (Get-PnPTerm)

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store, pnp-powershell

When trying to run a Get-PnPTerm cmdlet to return all terms in a large termset (10k or even 60k items), most of the time I get a timeout error as below:

> Get-PnPTerm : The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply
>   after 00:00:30. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to
>   Request or increase the SendTimeout value  on the Binding. The time
>   allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer
>   timeout.

Is there a way to increase this timeout value in SPO? 
If not, is there a better way to return all those terms, e.g. in smaller batches and add to an array?

Thanks

---

UPDATE

---

Basically I have an array of IDs ($IDs) an I'm trying to check if any of those ids are already in a term set.

```
#Get all existing terms
$allTerms = Get-PnPTerm -TermGroup $termGroup -TermSet $termSet -ErrorAction Stop | Select Name, Id 

#Convert to string for easy matching
$strAllTerms = $allTerms | Out-String -Stream

foreach ($id in $ids){
if ($strAllTerms -match $id) {*do something*}
}
```

Comment: Yes, You could retrieve terms in smaller batches and I would recommend that. Solutions are numerous, but the best solution for You will be based on Your existing code - could You provide that?

Comment: Sure, added code to my initial post. 
I also have there some loops if there's a timeout when getting terms, but the code I posted above presents the general idea.

Comment: @KristapsVilerts have you had a chance to look at this? ;) Thanks!